# Camel producerTemplate is not injected in spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, apache-camel

I'm using Spring MVC and Camel in my project, but encountering an issue that the producerTemplate is not able to be Autowired. Please check details below,

File web.xml:

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

File ispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<import resource="camel-config.xml"/>
```

File camel-config.xml, define camelContext

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.camel.routes"/>
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="myproject.camel">
     <contextScan/>
 <template id="producerTemplate"/>
</camelContext>
```

And here is my JAVA class:

```
package com.myproject.connector.camel;
public class CamelConnectorImp{
    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate; //This is null after starting
    producerTemplate.requestBodyAndHeaders(serviceEndpoint,request, headers);
...
}
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to make sure CammelConnectorImp is a known bean to Spring.

```
@Bean
public class CamelConnectorImp{ ..
```

**(Update:)**

You should probably scan for this pojo as well, so that the @Bean gets picked up:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.camel.routes,com.myproject.connector.camel"/>
```

or something similar will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally figured it out. 
The cause was that, I didn't use the bean in Application context, instead, I created that connector by this way,

```
IConnector connector = new CamelConnectorImp();
```

This is wrong, no wonder that camelContext is not in this instance.

My fault.

Comment: Yes, like my answer states, you should pick up the CamelConnectorImp as a bean.