# Camel ProducerTemplate not injected with annotation config

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

First of all, I know there are very similar questions ([Camel producerTemplate is not injected in spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265703/camel-producertemplate-is-not-injected-in-spring-mvc) and [Initializing camel from Spring annotation config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101196/initializing-camel-from-spring-annotation-config)) but they don't help in my case.

I have a bean which sends messages with ProducerTemplate:

```
public class SimpleProducer {

   @Produce(uri = "activemq:queue:simple")
   private ProducerTemplate activeMqProducer;

   public void send(String message) {
      activeMqProducer.sendBody(message);
   }
}
```

When I use annotation driven configuration like below, it trhows NPE from the send method (activeMqProducer is not injected):

```
@Configuration
public class AnnotationConfigApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AnnotationConfigApp.class);
      SimpleProducer simpleProducer = context.getBean(SimpleProducer.class);
      simpleProducer.send("Hello World!");
   }

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext ctx;

   @Bean
   public SimpleProducer simpleProducer() {
      return new SimpleProducer();
   }

   @Bean
   public CamelContext camelContext() throws Exception {
      CamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext(ctx);
      camelContext.start();
      return camelContext;
   }
}
```

while using equivalent (at least I believe so) XML configuration, it sucessfully sends a message to ActiveMQ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:spring="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
       <bean id="simpleProducer" class="makasprzak.so.camel.producer.testing.SimpleProducer"/>
       <spring:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="simple.sender" />
</beans>
```

initialized like this:

```
public class XmlConfigApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
      SimpleProducer simpleProducer = context.getBean(SimpleProducer.class);
      simpleProducer.send("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

I've been playing with CamelContext implementation a bit, tried DefaultCamelContext or some SpringCamelContextFactory - no luck.

The problematic code is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/makasprzak/camel-producer-testing/tree/87453fa63da1fd427ebfb6f3c743e5882adcc2a9)

```
<properties>
    <camel.version>2.15.2</camel.version>
    <activemq.version>5.10.0</activemq.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

What did I miss in the annotation configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extend org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration in AnnotationConfigApp class

Comment: Applied you answer to [GitHub example](https://github.com/makasprzak/camel-producer-testing/commit/a3a9f4b396f107efec951af7a36bf7436a0e2d76)